# how to i split this list into the same list without creating new list

Tags: python, list, split

how do I split this list

```py
['charmander|4/16/2022 18:5:52|Good to see you!', 'charmander|4/16/2022 18:6:0|Good to see you!']
```

to

```py
['charmander', '4/16/2022 18:5:52', 'Good to see you!' , 'charmander', '4/16/2022 18:5:52', 'Good to see you!']
```

by the way, this list is part of a txt file and has been split already by doing this

```py
file = open('messages/' + username + '.txt', 'r')

data = file.read().strip()

results = data.split("\n")
```

Comment: You have to use `data.split('|')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using string.split("|")

```
l = ['charmander|4/16/2022 18:5:52|Good to see you!', 'charmander|4/16/2022 18:6:0|Good to see you!']
newList = []
for val in l:
    newList += (val.split("|"))

Output:
['charmander',
 '4/16/2022 18:5:52',
 'Good to see you!',
 'charmander',
 '4/16/2022 18:6:0',
 'Good to see you!']
```

Comment: theres an error and it says "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'"

Comment: What did you try? Can you show me your input

Comment: def print_messages(username):
    file = open('messages/' + username + '.txt', 'r')
    data = file.read().strip()
    results = data.split("\n")
    newList = []
    for c in results:
        newList += (results.split("|"))
    print(newList)

Comment: im sorry if that is organized terribly this is my first time on here

Comment: also im extracting the file from a txt file

Comment: just so you know

Comment: Can you show me what is the output of "results" variable?

Comment: ['charmander|4/16/2022 18:41:14|Good to see you!', 'charmander|4/16/2022 18:41:21|Good to see you!']

Comment: the results is getting extracted from a txt file that looks like this : charmander|4/16/2022 18:41:14|Good to see you!
charmander|4/16/2022 18:41:21|Good to see you!

Comment: Ah. I see a mistake in yout code. It should be c.split not results.split

Comment: wait that comment didn't include a line break that shows on the the txt file

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try a [**list-comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open(f'messages/{username}.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().strip()
results = [s.split('|') for s in data.split('\n')]
print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
['charmander', '4/16/2022 18:5:52', 'Good to see you!' , 'charmander', '4/16/2022 18:5:52', 'Good to see you!']
```